# How to add Question mark to Button android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to add a question mark like the below Image in Android. How do I do it? I have tried using Images, but those are not the kind I want. I need a kind of tooltip to appear. Is there any way to achieve this?

[image: Image Link]

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative layout. Create a image with the folder icon and then another layout for question mark. Add both of them to the relative layout and assign properties alignparentright and alignparenttop to the questionmark layout. this should solve your problem.